# PHP exec returns empty string while executing Python script

Tags: php, python

I am trying to run a Python script inside PHP and show the output.

I tried with simple test.py inside PHP, which print hello world without problem. But when I try to execute my desired command from PHP script the `exec()` returns empty string instead of output.

So the here is my php script. Below snippets works fine:

```
$output = exec("python test.py"); 
var_dump($output);
```

But not the desired one.

```
$command = "python -m scripts.label_image --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --image=".$uploadfile;
$output = exec($command);
var_dump($output);
```

so the folder structure is:

```
/var/www/mysite/
              -scripts(folder which contains python scripts)
              -tf_files(folder with other files)
              -uploads (image folder)
```

Can someone tell me what is going wrong?

Sample output in stdout/shell:

[image: shell output of python script]

Comment: Where and how is the desired one being called?

Comment: @Dave 

Hi Dave, I am uploading a image file using a form and which is processed in upload.php file. I am also executing the command in upload.php. The upload.php file is in parent folder mysite.

Comment: Is the path to where Python is installed visible to the web server? For the version you posted that works fine where and how did you run it?

Comment: Hi dave, 
I am using ubuntu 18.04. The path to python is  "/usr/bin/python" which is included at the beginning of every python script i used. 
Although I did not understand what you meant by "where Python is installed visible to the web server". But as test.py can run successfully from localhost I guess python is visible to web server. 
Does it answer your question?

Comment: Does your desired command work as expected from the shell?

Comment: Is your script actually printing anything to its stdout ?

Comment: @Dave yes it works perfectly in shell.  I also copied my original project similarly to localhost host and ran the exact same command. Only exception is that this time the input image argument is passing through php.

Comment: Try changing `$output = exec($command);` to `exec($command,$output);` and see what you get please.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  you meant python script or php script? php scripts returning empty strings and python script works fine in shell.

Comment: @Makau the python script of course.

Comment: @Dave  I get  this 
"Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/mysite/upload.php on line 28
Array"

Comment: Do a `print_r($output)` then and see what the array contains.

Comment: @Dave I got "Array ( )"  :(

Comment: Which tells me that your Python program is likely not outputting anything. But, one more suggestion from the [PHP manual on exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) try adding `2>&1` to the call to your Python program. If you use a 3rd variable to the exec call the return value will be provided which may be helpful.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers please see the updated question. I have added a screenshot of the sample output of python script in shell.

Comment: @Dave I added a 3rd argument in exec and it returns 1(one).

Comment: Sorry but I'm fresh out of suggestions on this one. Not seeing anything to explain why you aren't getting the output.

Answer (score 0):

the variable $output should an argument.
If you do this, you should get only the last output of your script.

```
exec("python test.py", $output); 
var_dump($output);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php